# cannot import name 'colored' from 'termcolor'

Tags: python, termcolor

I'm trying to use termcolor in python3 using termcolor tutorial but i can't import colored from termcolor

```
from termcolor import colored
text = colored("Hello world", "green")
print(text)
```

it giving me

```
E:\>python termcolor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "termcolor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from termcolor import colored
  File "E:\termcolor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from termcolor import colored
ImportError: cannot import name 'colored' from 'termcolor' (E:\termcolor.py)
```

Comment: Is your own Python script named `termcolor.py`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is

Comment: Well, that's the problem. You're shadowing the library.

Comment: So, it is importing itself. Just rename it.

Comment: got new problem, adding it now on the post

Comment: **rename your file into another name. don't give library names.**